# How do I correctly get all posts within the last year using the query_posts function?

Tags: query-posts

Specifically, I am making a custom rss feed.  I have modeled it after the rss2 feed that is in the wp-includes folder.  I can successfully retrieve all posts using the standard query_posts('posts_per_page=-1').

Here is how I am attempting to get just the ones posted in the past year:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$newdate = strtotime ( '-1 year' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
$ayearago = date( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );

function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . $ayearago . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

query_posts($query_string);
```

Yes this returns only posts from 2011 forward.  Can someone help me figure out why?

Here is the main source code from my custom feed page called feed-postlist.php:

```
    /**
 * Custom RSS Feed
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>

<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>
>
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$newdate = strtotime ( '-1 year' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
$ayearago = date( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );

function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date >= DATE('" . $ayearago . "')";
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

query_posts('posts_per_page=-1');
?>
<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
    <description><?php bloginfo_rss("description") ?></description>
    <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></lastBuildDate>
    <language><?php echo get_option('rss_language'); ?></language>
    <sy:updatePeriod><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_period', 'hourly' ); ?></sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_frequency', '1' ); ?></sy:updateFrequency>
    <?php do_action('rss2_head'); ?>
    <?php while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <item>
```

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: In your example code you refer to `$query_string` but don't include the code where you assign it nor are you explaining the context in which you are calling `query_posts()` *(which isn't a function that people should usually call; normally `get_posts()` or even `new WP_Query()` is better.)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel - Please see my edit above for more information:  I changed `$query_string` to `posts_per_page=-1` but it still does not return any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Ryan Long:**

You have two problems:

1. You need to wrap the result of `date( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );` in a SQL `DATE()` function, and
2. You define `$ayearago` outside of the `filter_where()` function so it's not in scope within the function. You need to move the code that sets `$ayearago` into the `filter_where()` function like this:

```
function yoursite_filter_where($where = '') {
  $today = date('Y-m-d');
  $newdate = strtotime ( '-1 year' , strtotime ( $today ) ) ;
  $ayearago = date( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
  $where .= " AND post_date >= DATE('{$ayearago}')";
  return $where;
}
```

Let me know if that works for you...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. However doing what you suggest here doesn't return any posts.

I also tried formatting it like this:

$where .= " AND post_date >= DATE('" . $ayearago . "')";
However this also returned no results.

Comment: @Ryan Lang - Damn I hate when the answer is staring at me and I miss it.  Fingers crossed, I think you'll find my updated code works for you.

Comment: Bingo! That worked.  A simple scope issue, nice catch.  Thanks for the help.  I also need to make sure to add the query_posts('posts_per_page=-1') to make it show all the posts instead of using the default posts per page in the admin settings.

Comment: @Ryan Lang - *"A simple scope issue,"* - Yeah, it's the things I don't look for, I look for the harder stuff. Sometimes the easy stuff is just completely invisible!  BTW, you might want to use `get_posts()` instead of `query_posts()` as it can be more robust. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698576/get-posts-doesnt-work-but-query-posts-does-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this:

```
$today = getdate();
$lastyear = $today[ 'year' ] - 1;

query_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'year' => $lastyear,
    ) );
```

or

```
function your_function() {
    $today = getdate();
    $lastyear = $today['year'] - 1;
    set_query_var( 'year', $lastyear );
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'your_function' );
```

Also for feed, might wanna add `is_feed()`

Comment: actually I take that back.  Both of them only return posts that were posted in the previous year (2010 in this case).  What I am wanting is all post within the past year from the current date.

Comment: Nice suggestion. One thing is it unfortunately doesn't handle is a *"rolling year ago"* requirement.